# 406 Not Acceptable on HTML website

Tags: html, error-handling, http-status-code-404

Today I've noticed my website http://tuka.mx is getting this error: Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /servicios.html could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 406 Not Acceptable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Sometimes it works just fine, sometimes it keeps getting the error, someone knows how to fix it? I believe there's something wrong with the server since I've been experiencieng mail issues too.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you contact your hosting company? Do you see anything unusual on your access.log? Your site is unstable and time out most of the time and occasionally getting a 406. One reason why you are seeing the HTTP error 406 is because there is a mod_security rule setting on the server. Many web hosting companies set up the mod_security rule on their Apache web servers to protect it from hackers. BTW, you have a typo on 'device' on your html header `<meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1.0">`